# GitLab Auto DevOps Failure - Invalid Reference Format

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus

When I try to run Auto DevOps on GitLab I keep running into this issue. I've been searching the web with no solution thus far.

> ```
> -----> Discovering process types
> Default types for  -> web
>    + docker commit ci_job_build_33 /master:17f9b8836e2734ccba061d851705eb879ea15177
>  invalid reference format
> ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
> ```

Comment: Are yo using any kind of environment variable here?