# gitlab k8s auto devops, invalid reference format

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

need help with the default gitlab auto devops process.  i am using gitlab 12.8.5 by docker, and minikube v1.8.1. when i follow the [quick start guide](http://gitlab.bubumaoapp.com/help/topics/autodevops/quick_start_guide) i stuck in the auto build process, bellow is the screenshot:
[invalid reference format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwkWQ.png)

```
 Checking out 901de3a8 as master...
 Skipping Git submodules setup
$ if [[ -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]]; then # collapsed multi-line command
00:03
 $ /build/build.sh
 Building Heroku-based application using gliderlabs/herokuish docker image...
 invalid reference format
 invalid reference format
 invalid argument "/master:901de3a8bd5573f4a049b1457d28bc1592ba6bf9" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
 See 'docker build --help'.
 ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

also i have found some similar questions here :

- [GitLab CI invalid argument on job for Docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486026/gitlab-ci-invalid-argument-on-job-for-docker-build)
- [GitLab default autodevops CI: invalid tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571382/gitlab-default-autodevops-ci-invalid-tag-name)
- [GitLab Auto DevOps Failure - Invalid Reference Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061307/gitlab-auto-devops-failure-invalid-reference-format)

however, i still can't find the solution. please help,thinks.

Billy

Answer (score 1):

in case someone have the same issue. i fixed the error by enable the Container Registry, thanks